# Extract lines from a text file

Tags: r, extract

I have a text file in the following format and I wish to extract certain lines using `R`.

`read.table("")` also does not seem to work...

```
FiberLab 3

Name:   3_0002  
Date:   08-06-12  
Time:   14:42  
Company:    SLU  
Sample ID-Place:    034-UPSC Spruce  
Fibers:     10006   526 526 pcs  
Weight:     0.000   mg  
L(n)/L(l)/L(w):  1.22    2.28    2.75   mm  
L(n)/L(l)/L(w):  1.11    2.05    2.44   mm  
Width:  29.97   µm  
CWT:     7.90   µm  
Coar:   0.000   mg/m
```

Answer (score 4):

For this kind of non-tabular data, `read.table` is not going to work. What I would try is to read the data using `readLines`, and process from there using regular expressions (`grep`, `sub`, etc).